# How Can I Test the Silverlight Install Process

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-2.0

I would like to customize the user install process for my Silverlight application. I would need to repeatedly go through the installation process on my development workstation Short of uninstalling before each change I make and going through the install process again, is there a way to make my browser think Silverlight is not installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to make your browser think SL is not installed.

In Internet Explorer 8, I can go to Tools > Manage Add-ons.  From there, I select to Show "All add-ons."  I then click on Microsoft Silverlight and click "Disable."

I saw Tim Heuer do this process to demonstrate the look of Silverlight being uninstalled in an application.

I imagine there's a way to disable plug-ins, add-ons, extensions, etc. for other browsers.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6&displaylang=en) or [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) instance and keep resetting it to a "before Silverlight was installed" snapshot.